# Send transaction using MetaMask injected web 3

Tags: transactions, web3js, dapp-development, metamask

Metamasks injected web3 gives an error when using `web3.eth.sendTransaction()`

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:web3.eth.accounts[0], to:'', data: // hash to interact with contraact, gas:85000});
```

[image]

What would be a way to use Metamask to have a website prompt a user to sign a transaction ?

Comment: This error message was pretty bad, it will be improved in a future version thanks to your question! https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-plugin/pull/751

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the last argument to `sendTransaction`, the callback `function(error, transactionHash) { ... }`

The [MetaMask FAQ](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#dizzy-all-async---think-of-metamask-as-a-light-client) states:

**All Async - Think of MetaMask as a light client**

> The user does not have the full blockchain on their machine and so
>   data lookups can be a little slow. For this reason, we are unable to
>   support most synchronous methods. The exception to this is:
>
> eth_accounts (web3.eth.accounts)
>
> eth_coinbase (web3.eth.coinbase)
>
> Usually a method call can be made async by simply adding a callback as
>   the last argument to a synchronous method.
>
> See ethereum wiki on "using callbacks"
>
> Not only is this a technical limitation, it's also a user experience
>   issue. When you use synchronous calls, you block the user's interface,
>   and so it's a generally bad practice anyways. Think of this API
>   restriction as a gift to your users.

So all calls to web3.js should have a callback as their last argument: the only calls where that's not needed are for `web3.eth.accounts` and `web3.eth.coinbase`.  The generic form of the callback is `function(error, result)`.

Comment: Useful about those two commands. I'm looking in to using `deasync`

Comment: There is no clear guide to how to successfully get this to work anywhere. Code of a properly formatted button that works with MetaMask would be useful. It's poorly documented.

Comment: @TrumpPaiPence please try looking for and contacting MetaMask support.

Answer (score 2):

```
var receiver = "0x541209bd9C60cDb11A5076b785ba1BD44cd15768";  
var sender = web3.eth.accounts[0];
web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:receiver,
                        from:sender, 
                       value:web3.toWei("0.5", "ether")}
                        ,function (err, res){});
```