# Send Multiple transactions in ethereum from an eth address

Tags: metamask

I don't know if this question was already answered but my question is about a normal wallet address and not a smartcontract.

So what I want to do is to launch multiple transactions with small gaz price and let them until they are executed. Is it possible?

Can we do that with metamask for instance?

Also can anyone tell me how it can be possible in the technical part (I mean the blockchain need by construction to have only a transaction from the same address in a block, and the following transaction should be in another block)?

Thank you for your responses

Comment: Send Transaction uses `nonce` that makes the transactions mined as per the sent sequences. You can send any number of transactions and they would all be mined in the sequence. Hope this addresses your need.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I think it does. How it does work for a simple wallet? Does metamask for instance support that?

Comment: Yes, it supports. Check https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/9385/20357 and https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/32959/20357 to learn about it

Answer (score -1):

Yes it possible.

Advantages of it is.

1. In single transaction you can send tokens to multiple address
2. Save time for sending tokens
3. Save gas value

Check below transaction as its already implemented and working without any issue.

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xa944a9d56d20d6740c6e1abd5a9fe90105f66c6946ee040cc58719054f5a7586

Comment: Question is about a normal address, not a contract.

Comment: Yes it's distributer to normal address only.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's for normal address only. As function called for do that its showing contract address in to but if you will check destination address for tokens all are normal address. So in 1 transaction 100. Normal address present.

Check below transaction

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa44e629bfd5958a5f2375929734af1bc1361455503eebbc85b397c1b178c1d11